# Run time error '1004' Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba

```
nSectionSetupRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match( _
      Worksheets("Items").Cells(nRow, 1), _
      Worksheets("SectionSetup").Range("B1:B" & _
      Worksheets("SectionSetup").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row), 0)
```

i am facing issue here and using excel 97-2003 worksheet type of excel

Answer (score 1):

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` will raise a run-time error if there's no match.

`Application.Match` will instead return an error value which you can test for using `IsError()`

E.g:

```
Dim m 'variant
m = Application.Match(lookupValue, lookupRange, 0)
If Not IsError(m) Then
    'got a match
Else
    'no match
End If
```